# Monomorphism in category theory.

Tags: category-theory

Why if $\text{kernel} f=\text{zero morphism}$ then $f$ is a monomorphism?
The converse is very easy, but for this I'm tried to find sufficient condition to equivalent of two morphism(to use the definition of monomorphism in category theory) , but I couldn't.

Comment: What category are we working in? A general category? An abelian category?

Comment: General category

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Well, the notion of a "zero morphism" does not exist in a general category...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel of a morphism $f$ is defined in a pointed category, that is, a category with a zero object, as the equalizer of $f$ and $0$. But your proposition is not true in that context: consider for instance the category of pointed topological spaces and the natural map $f:S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$, where the base point of $S^1\vee S^1$ is anything other than the wedge point. Then since $f$ is injective away from the wedge point, the kernel of $f$ is the zero object-but $f$ is not a monomorphism.

The proposition holds, instead, in any pointed category enriched over abelian groups, for instance, an additive category. Then if $f$ has zero kernel and $fg=fh$, $f(g-h)=0$ so $g-h$ factors through the kernel, that is, through the zero object, and hence $g-h=0$ and $g=h$.